# When to use <router-link> vs <a>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Should I always be using `<router-link>` over `<a>` even if I am linking to something like a social media page outside the app?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<router-link>` is intended for in-app links (e.g., to a page within your app). Use `<a>` for external links.

Comment: On top, from the router documentation: <router-link> is preferred over hard-coded <a href="..."> for the following reasons:

It works the same way in both HTML5 history mode and hash mode, so if you ever decide to switch mode, or when the router falls back to hash mode in IE9, nothing needs to be changed.

In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page.

When you are using the base option in HTML5 history mode, you don't need to include it in to prop's URLs.

#

Answer (score 7):

Router link : if we use router link the page will not reload but with `<a>` link the navigation occured through page refresh.

Comment: One other thing to note is that because you will not switch page relative URLs will not work with router-link. For instance you have a /user page and you want to implement a post create if you switch over to that page using router link your relative post will look like /create while the other way around it will look like user/create

Answer (score 1):

‘vue-router’ is a separate package to Vue and is installed by ‘webpack’.

Routes are set up in router/index.js

Import to Router from vue-router which is in node_modules.

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
... new Router...
```

creates an instance of Router which is an object with a property ‘routes’ which is an array of object. Each of those objects is a route with properties for ‘path’, ‘name’ which is what it is called and ‘component’, the component that is called when the route is used.

```
{
      path: '/about',
      name: 'About',
      component: About
    }
```

We need to import the component and we use the @ which brings the path to the root of the project which is the ‘src’ directory.

```
import About from '@/components/About'
```

The component gets loaded into the root component App.vue using,

```
<router-view/>
```

and where that tag is in the App.vue. This would allow us to place a navbar, header and footer for example around this About component. So that when you go to …/about only the about component in the page changes and the whole page doesn’t refresh.

Next create a NavBar component and place it in the App.vue template.

This will work,

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

however in vue it should be done like this,

```
<router-link to="/about>About</router-link>
```

When <router-link> is rendered to the browser it becomes <a> so in the css we still reference it as ‘a’ not as ‘router-link’.

We can data bind using the ‘to’ attribute in <router-link>like this,

```
:to={ name: 'About'}
```

where ‘name’ is the property in the ‘routes’ array of object in the main.js routes. This makes the route dynamic.

Using this data bind to change to ‘/about’ to something else such as ‘abt’ you only need to change,

```
path: 'abt',
```

in the routes array of objects.